# JSF2 /......registerHostUser.xhtml @9,9 <h:head> Tag Library supports namespace: http://java.sun.com/jsf/html, but no tag was defined for name: head

Tags: jsf, maven, glassfish, jsf-2, facelets

i am new to JSF 2 as i am trying to do a hello world example to familarise myself, i hit this error which i have been trying out for quite some days.

**StackTrace**

```
om.sun.facelets.tag.TagException: /facelets/register/host/registerHostUser.xhtml @9,9 <h:head> Tag Library supports namespace: http://java.sun.com/jsf/html, but no tag was defined for name: head
at com.sun.facelets.compiler.CompilationManager.pushTag(CompilationManager.java:193)
at com.sun.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler$CompilationHandler.startElement(SAXCompiler.java:194)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:501)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:767)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:400)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2755)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:395)
at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:198)
at com.sun.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompile(SAXCompiler.java:232)
at com.sun.facelets.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:105)
at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.createFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:218)
at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:149)
at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:100)
at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.buildView(FaceletViewHandler.java:517)
at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:567)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:410)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1534)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:326)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:227)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:170)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>sg.java</groupId>
<artifactId>web.vms</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>${faces.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${faces.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.facelets</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-facelets</artifactId>
        <version>${facelets.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>${primeFaces.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>vms</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>java.net</id>
        <name>java.net</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <name>Prime Technology Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.prime.com.tr</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>

    <!-- http://community.jboss.org/wiki/MavenGettingStarted-Developers -->
    <repository>
        <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
        <name>JBoss Public Repository Group</name>
        <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<properties>
    <junit.version>4.8.2</junit.version>
    <primeFaces.version>2.2</primeFaces.version>
    <faces.version>2.0.3</faces.version>
    <javaee.version>1.0.0.Final</javaee.version>
    <facelets.version>1.1.15.B1</facelets.version>
</properties>
```

**registerHostUser.xhtml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:head>
    <title>Register Host User</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        Register Host User<br />

        Email: <h:inputText label="Email" id="email"
            value="#{hostUserRegistrationBackingBean.email}" required="true" />
        <h:message for="email" />

        <p></p>

        <h:commandButton value="Register" action="confirm" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

**faces-config.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd">
    <application>
        <view-handler>com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler</view-handler>

        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>en</default-locale>
        </locale-config>

        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>sg.java.web.vms.messages</base-name>
            <var>msg</var>
        </resource-bundle>
    </application>
</faces-config>
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/facelets/register/host/registerHostUser.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure how exactly this is caused and how exactly Maven plays a role since I don't use it, but I see at least three potential causes:

1. You have JSF 1.x libraries in your `/WEB-INF/lib` or elsewhere in classpath. Remove it (or instruct Maven to not include them). Glassfish 3 already ships with builtin JSF 2.x libraries. The `<h:head>` was namely introduced in JSF 2.0 and is thus absent in JSF 1.x.
2. The `FaceletViewHandler` declaration in `faces-config.xml` is entirely superfluous. Remove it. This is only mandatory when you're using JSF 1.x. JSF 2.x uses by default Facelets. If you did add it because you couldn't get Facelets to run, then the whole problem is definitely caused by cause #1 (and then remove any Facelets 1.x libraries as well).
3. The `web.xml` is not been declared as Servlet 3.0. I'm not sure how Glassfish acts on this with regard to the provided JSF implementation, but you should be declaring Servlet 3.0 whenever the container supports it.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <web-app
       xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
       xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
       id="Your_Webapp_ID" version="3.0">

       <!-- Config here -->

   </web-app>
   ```

   Also the `com.sun.faces.expressionFactory` param is entirely superfluous with Servlet 3.0 since it is already the Glassfish-default one.

---

Unrelated to the concrete problem, I recommend to bring the `FacesServlet` mappings to a minimum. Stick to the `*.xhtml` one and get rid of the others.

Comment: The post by BalusC solved the problem.

Using a 3.0 web.xml declaration helped.

Comment: Hi BalusC, thank you for your advise. The servlet 2.5 web.xml declaration was cause.

Comment: This actually surprises me a bit. I know that Glassfish is pretty strict, but JSF 2.0 is designed to be backwards compatible with Servlet 2.5. This goes overboard. Thank you for mentioning the actual cause :)

Comment: For what is worth, I posted an [issue report](http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-16163).

Comment: Great BalusC, i will be keeping an eye to this report.